# OS10.11, Xcode7.0.1, Can't upload app to store

Tags: macos, submit, xcode7, application-loader

When I upload my app by application loader, I meet those errors, you can see it below

[image]

Before upgrade Xcode, everything is ok. so it's really strange...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Considering all of the things that break when a new version of `OS X` gets released it's anything but "strange"... I'd say more like the "norm"... It looks like a problem with that framework obviously.

Comment: Looks like there is some user rights issue. Try to create mentioned folder at the specified path

Comment: Now by Xcode, the result is successful, but can't find new version in website, by application loader also get those error....